# How do I bind two elements into a single Link Button ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspx-user-control

I am trying to bind two elements from a list to a Link Button. The following works separately on two link buttons:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" ForeColor="Black" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:LinkButton>

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" ForeColor="Black" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserID") %>' OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

I want to do it so on the Text Attribute it holds both Name and UserID Bind.

For example;

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" ForeColor="Black" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserID") % + " " + <%# Bind("Name") %>' OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

How Can I achieve this?

Comment: It's definitely do-able. For one, it looks like you h ave a syntax issue in your example, where `%` occurs in the middle of the concatenation. If fixing that doesn't resolve the issue you could always concatenate the fields on the backend and then bind a single element on your frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this. Bind comma separated values in [CommandArgument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandargument?view=netframework-4.8) property of [LinkButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton?view=netframework-4.8):

```
CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Name") + ";" + Eval("UserID") %>'
```

then on click:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
 LinkButton lnkButton = (LinkButton)sender;
 string[] args = lnkButton.CommandArgument.Split(';');

 string name = string.Empty, userId = string.Empty;
 if (args.Length == 2)
 {
   name = args[0];
   userId = args[1];
 }
}
```